# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: foreach, php

The code down below delete files inside the folder " Images " every 60 seconds, it works, but when the folder is empty it says: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
How can that be fixed like if there is no files, say " folder empty instead of that warning..

```
<?php
$expiretime=1; 

$tmpFolder="Images/";
$fileTypes="*.*";

foreach (glob($tmpFolder . $fileTypes) as $Filename) {

// Read file creation time
$FileCreationTime = filectime($Filename);

// Calculate file age in seconds
$FileAge = time() - $FileCreationTime;

// Is the file older than the given time span?
if ($FileAge > ($expiretime * 60)){

// Now do something with the olders files...

echo "The file $Filename is older than $expiretime minutes\r\n";

//delete files:
unlink($Filename);
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since glob() may not reliably return an empty array for an empty match ([See "note" in Return section of the docs)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), you just need an `if` statement protecting your loop, like so:

```
$files = glob($tmpFolder . $fileTypes);
if (is_array($files) && count($files) > 0) {
    foreach($files as $Filename) {
        // Read file creation time
        $FileCreationTime = filectime($Filename);

        // Calculate file age in seconds
        $FileAge = time() - $FileCreationTime;

        // Is the file older than the given time span?
        if ($FileAge > ($expiretime * 60)){

        // Now do something with the olders files...

        echo "The file $Filename is older than $expiretime minutes\r\n";

        //delete files:
        unlink($Filename);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Your error here...';
}
```

Comment: Check your braces... just take what you had and wrap it in this if block.

Comment: ctrahey could you please implant that exmaple inside the code i have posted to show me how it should be placed, please? i'm going acept right away

Comment: I've pasted the original loop contents where I had left a placeholder.